# Oracle database - get two rows (A,B) for every (COD) row

Tags: oracle, cte, case, coalesce, join

I have a Oracle database and a variable that can have a value for A and a value for B like in this example:

```
cod   cat  v1   v2   v3   
123   A    1    10   11
123   B    0    0    0
111   A    2    3    4
111   B    0    7    0
```

I have cod in a table RAP and the CAT is A or B if it has values v1,v2 or v3 in two different tables. For the upper result I must have

RAP:

```
id cod den
1  123 aaa
2  111 bbb
```

VAL1_A

```
fk_rap  v1  v2  v3
1       1   10  11
2       2   3   4
```

VAL1_B

```
fk_rap  v1  v2  v3
2       0   7   0
```

how can I write an script to do that so that if I don't have nothing in the `VAL1_B` to get an row with zero on B `cat` for the `cod`. So I have to get an `CAT` A and B for every `COD`. I don't have anywhere the value A or B, it's just a text to put in `CAT` for the values it has in `VAL1_A` and `VAL1_B`.

I'm making something like this:

```
        with cte as
            (select rap.cod,
                    case
                     when (coalesce(val1_a.v1,0)<>0 or
                           coalesce(val1_a.v2,0)<>0 or
                           coalesce(val1_a.v3,0)<>0)
                     then
                        'A'
                     when (coalesce(val1_b.v1,0)<>0 or
                           coalesce(val1_b.v2,0)<>0 or
                           coalesce(val1_b.v3,0)<>0)
                     then
                        'B'
                    end
                     as cat,
                   coalesce(val1_a.v1,0) as v1_a,
                   coalesce(val1_a.v2,0) as v2_a,
                   coalesce(val1_a.v3,0) as v3_a,
                   coalesce(val1_b.v1,0) as v1_b,
                   coalesce(val1_b.v2,0) as v2_b,
                   coalesce(val1_b.v3,0) as v3_b
             from rap
                 full outer join val1_a on val1_a.fk_rap=rap.id
                 full outer join val1_b on val1_b.fk_rap=rap.id
           )
     select cod,
            cat,
            case when cat='A' then v1_a
                 when cat='B' then v1_b
            end
              as v1,
            case when cat='A' then v2_a
                 when cat='B' then v2_b
            end
              as v2,
            case when cat='A' then v3_a
                 when cat='B' then v3_b
            end
              as v3
     from cte
```

but I have only a value for A or B... I want a value for A and one for B....
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with UNION ALL:

```
with cte as
        (select rap.cod,
                case
                 when (coalesce(val1_a.v1,0)<>0 or
                       coalesce(val1_a.v2,0)<>0 or
                       coalesce(val1_a.v3,0)<>0)
                 then
                    'A'
                end
                 as cat,
               coalesce(val1_a.v1,0) as v1_a,
               coalesce(val1_a.v2,0) as v2_a,
               coalesce(val1_a.v3,0) as v3_a,
               coalesce(val1_b.v1,0) as v1_b,
               coalesce(val1_b.v2,0) as v2_b,
               coalesce(val1_b.v3,0) as v3_b
         from rap
             full outer join val1_a on val1_a.fk_rap=rap.id
             full outer join val1_b on val1_b.fk_rap=rap.id
         UNION ALL
         select rap.cod,
                case
                 when (coalesce(val1_b.v1,0)<>0 or
                       coalesce(val1_b.v2,0)<>0 or
                       coalesce(val1_b.v3,0)<>0)
                 then
                    'B'
                end
                 as cat,
               coalesce(val1_a.v1,0) as v1_a,
               coalesce(val1_a.v2,0) as v2_a,
               coalesce(val1_a.v3,0) as v3_a,
               coalesce(val1_b.v1,0) as v1_b,
               coalesce(val1_b.v2,0) as v2_b,
               coalesce(val1_b.v3,0) as v3_b
         from rap
             full outer join val1_a on val1_a.fk_rap=rap.id
             full outer join val1_b on val1_b.fk_rap=rap.id
       )
 select cod,
        cat,
        case when cat='A' then v1_a
             when cat='B' then v1_b
        end
          as v1,
        case when cat='A' then v2_a
             when cat='B' then v2_b
        end
          as v2,
        case when cat='A' then v3_a
             when cat='B' then v3_b
        end
          as v3
 from cte
```